# How to properly use SecureRandom 12 digit number?

Tags: java, random, secure-random

I am trying to create a random number use SecureRandom. It must be digits only (0123456789) and be 12 characters long. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    synchronized (secureRandom) {
        final byte[] random = new byte[12];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(random);
        return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(random);
    }
```

I am getting the following:

```
IHmv_qsWMZ0teI_-
```

Comment: Base64 encoding largely uses letters

Comment: You will get digits for each element of that array with `(0xFF & random[i]) % 10)`

Comment: There's no point synchronizing on `secureRandom` as no other thread can possibly have a reference to it.

Comment: @tgdavies ok thanks. but how would i come up with a solution for a randm 12 digit number.

Comment: @g00se has already explained that.

Comment: ok, trying to figure out a solution based on that. a bit confused. @g00se on how to accomplish.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: You could ask `nextBytes` for just 5 random bytes. This is 5*8=40 bits. So the result can then be converted into a single integer number between 0 and 2^40. And 2^40 is just 10% above 10^12. You can probably afford to use plain rejection for those numbers that have the misfortune to lie above 10^12.

Comment: The easy solution is simply `num = secureRandom.nextLong() % 1000000000000L;`

Comment: Wouldn't using `%10` introduce a modulo bias in the resulting values?  As I understand it, this is highly undesirable, especially if used for encryption.

Comment: It *could* do. I'm not sure of the mathematics of it

Comment: I certainly wouldn't advance my comment as a solution. It was really just a reaction to *the existing array's presence*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a **random number** using SecureRandom. It must be digits only (0123456789) and be 12 characters long.

You could doit like this.  Just specify the origin and bound to match your digit count requirements.

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
long random =  secureRandom.nextLong(100_000_000_000L,1_000_000_000_000L);
System.out.println(random);
```

prints something like

```
426491911225
```

If it must be in a byte array of individual digits, you can do the following:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[12];
int loc = bytes.length - 1; // insert in reverse in array

while(random > 0) {
    bytes[loc--] = (byte)(random%10);
    random/=10;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

prints

```
[4, 2, 6, 4, 9, 1, 9, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]
```